# How can I make a CakePHP 3 time object remain consistent between AJAX and PHP?

Tags: time, timezone, cakephp-3.0

When I load a page with a Time object and echo it out on the page through PHP, I get this:

```
<?= $user->last_login ?>
// 12/30/14, 5:21 pm
```

When I load data through ajax, it's returned to me like this:

```
console.log(response.user.last_login);
// 2014-12-30T17:21:31+0000
```

I haven't set anything different from the default CakePHP 3 setup, and I need events that are added to the page (returned via ajax) to be in the same time format as events that were pulled on page load (return via PHP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default output in string format for Time objects is controlled by the `setToStringFormat` method http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#setting-the-default-locale-and-format-string

It is a good practice to not hardcode a format there, but to only change the current locale so that the right format is selected for you,

But the format that is used to encode to json is not possible to control it via configuration as it is a standard that dates should be presented in such format when encoded in a JSON API. Instead, what you can do is alter the `jsonSerialize` method in your `User` entity:

```
public function jsonSerialize() {
    $toEncode = parent::jsonSerialize();
    return ['last_login' => (string)$this->last_login] + $toEncode;
}
```

What it does is converting to string the `last_login` property before it is encoded to json. Converting to string will then use the globally configured `toString` format.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the format of the date using the [javascript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Examples)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y0zqvuuL/)

```
var date = new Date(response.user.last_login)
//returns a timestamp of 1419960091000

var n = date.getTime();

var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
month = month + 1;
//increment the month by 1 as it starts from 0
var year = date.getFullYear();
year = year.toString().substr(2,2); 
//this removes the first 2 characters to give yy, remove the above line for yyyy
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();

var period='am';
if(hours==0){ //At 00 hours we need to show 12 am
    hours=12;
}
else if(hours>12){
    hours=hours%12;
    //remove the above line for 24 hour format
    period='pm';
}
```

Now you can piece together the date in the required format

```
var last_login = day + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + period;
//gives 30/12/14 5:21 pm
```

Hope this helps!